# Qt : is good in a c++ class to have a widget field not declared as a pointer

Tags: c++, qt

```
class Foo : public QMainWindow
{
    MyWidget  *alertDlg_; 
    MyWidget   alertDlg2_; 
};
```

Is second field can be dangerous ?

Thanks

EDIT:
example of problem  :

```
{
    QPushButton button("button"); 
    QWidget widget;
    button.setParent(&widget);
} // crash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the Qt has it's own memory management, and if alertDlg2_ has a parent, you would get double deletion.

You can read more about qt object trees and ownership in [this article](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/objecttrees.html). You can see in it that it is not safe to do what you did in your edited example. That is why are you getting the crash.

Comment: so if parent of alertDlg2_ is Foo it's impossible to get problems ?

Comment: You don't need to set a parent for alertDlg2_ if it is declared like that. When Foo is destructed, alterDlg2_ will be destructed as well.

Comment: -1.  Qt objects are safe to use as declared.  The usual pattern is either to set a parent or to rely on another form of cleanup.  However, setting a parent object is also safe if the child object is cleaned up before the parent.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the double deletion statement is incorrect.

Comment: Sure it is. Read more about it in the article I linked in the edit :)

Comment: -1. Declaring a non-pointer field is fine if alertDlg is a child of of the Foo object. After all, members will be deleted before the base class. The link you provided seems to explain this well.

Comment: @wolfgang That article provides exactly the same example as in the OP's edit saying : *In this case, the order of destruction causes a problem.*. Also, the OP said that code causes a crash.

Comment: I was disputing the general statement that declaring non-pointer fields for widgets is dangerous, rather than the concrete example of what not to do.

Comment: @wolfgang Declaring non-pointers for widgets is safe, until your application starts crashing, with debugger showing a backtrace in the widget's destructor. I had that once happening in an application, and it took me a while to figure out why. Since then, I leave it up to qt to do it's thing.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll bow to your wisdom and take back my downvote; your answer would be improved in my eyes however if you edited it to make clear that it's OK in the form that was originally asked about in the question and that you just recommend against it based on bad experiences.